# How Do I Keep a CLI Script Running When I Close SSH Session

Tags: script, terminal

I am working on Martin F. O'Connor's internet connection monitor (https://github.com/mfoc/monitor-internet-connection), which records Internet Outages.

The script runs from the command line ($python3 -m monitor-internet-connection) and outputs any activity to the terminal screen in real time.

Closing the ssh session closes the script. Upon closing, the script writes the activity that was output to the ssh screen to a log file.

My objective is to be able to have the script run when the ssh session terminates (i.e., not close when the terminal is closed).

Comment: `nohup python3 -m monitor-internet-connection` any output will go to ./nohup.out in the current wroking directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are many ways to do this. Perhaps the *"most correct"* way is to `daemonize` the app. There's an [answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6374881/5395338) that provides some suggestions. You could do that yourself, or perhaps consider submitting that request to the author via creating a [new issue on his GitHub page](https://github.com/mfoc/monitor-internet-connection/issues).

Until that happens:

1. Have you tried just running it in the background?

```bsh
$ python3 -m monitor-internet-connection &
```

2. You could start the program as a `cron` job: `@reboot python3 ...`
3. If you're familiar with `screen` or `tmux` that's another way to do this... there's a [Q&A here that shows how](https://askubuntu.com/a/124903/831935). This approach has the advantage that you can restore it.
4. Maybe `nohup`?:

```bsh
$ nohup python3 -m monitor-internet-connection
```

What it seems you want to do is **detach** this program from your terminal session. If you search something like `linux run script and detach from terminal`, you will find some other choices I think.

Comment: Thank  you, Seamus. I tried all of your suggestions, so I appreciate the learning experience. #3 -- use screen or tmux -- turned out to be the best solution, precisely for the reason you suggested. BTW, I was unfamiliar with GitHub issue process ( after reading the response(s) to the one issue posted, it seemed rather condescending). I unsuccessfully had tried other means to contact the author.

Comment: @Brokenstick: RE: 'condescending': Don't be put off by that BS. Years ago, when I was initially exploring the "Unix-sphere", I tried OpenBSD. The project leader is a horrible asshole, but in all fairness, he did get things done. My point is to take it with a grain of salt, and don't let anyone discourage you from learning.

Answer (score 1):

A basic way to do this would be to use [screen or tmux](https://linuxhint.com/tmux_vs_screen/).

Closing the ssh session closes the active terminal but does not end the screen session, and you can later reattach using `screen -x` or `tmux attach`.

If you want to get more serious about things you could [write a simple systemd service](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-write-a-simple-systemd-service) to start the script at boot and keep it running in the background. You'd just need to have your script write to a file (perhaps just redirecting the output?) instead of `stdout`.

Comment: screen turned out to be the best solution. I have started looking at systemd service for another project; I like having the ability to find multiple solutions. Thank you.